# Pandas DataFrame to GeoDataFrame with Polygon geometry using groupby and lambda

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, geopandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` like this

```
name    loc_x    loc_y    grp_name
a1        1.0        2.0    set1
a2        2.0        3.0    set1
a3        3.2        4.1    set2
a4        7.9        4.2    set2
```

I want to generate a `GeoDataFrame` that generates a `polygon` using `loc_x` and `loc_y` grouped on `grp_name` and also includes a column `name` that has the values in my original data frame concatenated by `|`? The result should look like this

```
        name    geometry
set1    a1|a2   POLYGON ((1.0, 2.0)...)
set2    a3|a4   POLYGON ((3.2, 4.1)...)
```

I do this to get the geometry column but how do I also get an additional column with `name` concatenated from my base data frame?

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=df.groupby('grp_name').apply(
      lambda g: Polygon(gpd.points_from_xy(g['loc_x'], g['loc_y']))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- required a modification to your test data.  A polygon has a minimum of three points
- this comes down to knowing **pandas**. `groupby().apply()` provides a reference to dataframe for each group.  It's then simple to construct the two outputs you want per group

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""name    loc_x    loc_y    grp_name
a1        1.0        2.0    set1
a2        2.0        3.0    set1
a2.5      3.0        4.0    set1
a3        3.2        4.1    set2
a4        7.9        4.2    set2
a4.5      8.1        4.3    set2"""),sep="\s+",)

gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df.groupby("grp_name").apply(
        lambda d: pd.Series(
            {
                "name": "|".join(d["name"].tolist()),
                "geometry": shapely.geometry.Polygon(
                    d.loc[:, ["loc_x", "loc_y"]].values
                ),
            }
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this!